# How to collect the relevant information from the provided log?

Tags: c++, windows, parsing, file-io

I have a log file from which we have collect the relevant data.
Consider the log file as

```
--------other data---------------
Evaluating Function Test1 
--other data--
--other data--  
Output: This function excecuted successfully
--------other data---------------
--------other data---------------
Evaluating Function Test2
--other data- 
--other data--  
Output : This function excecuted successfully  
--other data--  
--other data--
```

I have to collect all outputs in file against each function, like

Test1 : Output: This function excecuted successfully

Test2 : Output: This function excecuted successfully

Can anyone provide me the approach for the collecting relevant data.

Comment: My approach would be to write some code to do this. Doing it by hand would be a pain. If I ran into problems with the code, I *might* consider asking for help in SO, but most likely I would find help in existing posts.

Comment: I have never use it, but think powergrep can solve you problem http://www.powergrep.com/

Comment: Well I haven't asked for code but the approach

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone provide me the approach for the collecting relevant data.

Yes (but your question is vague).

Your approach will have to (roughly) follow these steps:

- read the file line by line (there is a canonical way to do that - you will find it on SO)
- check each line and see if it matches a pattern you are interested in
- store the interesting lines in a container (if they match)
- interpret the stored lines (and display the results)